# ResponseFormat for WCF in JSON and XML at the same time?

Tags: c#, wcf

When requesting an object for example using REST, is it possible to get the response in json and xml format or do I have to create UriTemplates that are something like:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="&format=json?user/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]

[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="&format=xml?user/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

The reason I ask is because I may need one format returned for an app on an android phone for example and another type returned for an app on a laptop.

Also,  Can the methods have the same name such as Register or do I have to have one called:

RegisterJSON(User user) and another called RegisterXML(User user)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is available out of the box in [WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) (.NET 4.0). Check [AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior.automaticformatselectionenabled.aspx) property of WebHttpBehavior. You can also set this property from configuration. I showed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719594/return-multiple-response-from-wcf).

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, you need two separate, distinct methods - one for each response format. Also those methods need to have separate names, since the URL in REST must be unique - therefore, the method names must be unique.

With a bit of clever WCF extensibility coding, you can get dynamic response format as easy as adding an attribute on your service method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData?param1={i}&param2={s}")]
[DynamicResponseType]
public SampleResponseBody GetData(int i, string s)
{
    return new SampleResponseBody() 
               { 
                  Name = "Test",
                  Value = s, 
                  Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() 
               };
}
```

See that neat `[DynamicResponseType]` attribute there??

Check out the entire blog post by Damian Mehers: [WCF REST Services: Setting the response format based on request's expected type](http://damianblog.com/2008/10/31/wcf-rest-dynamic-response/) for all the great details!

**Update:** Unfortunately, it seems the sample code for this article isn't available anymore. Kyle Beyer built on top of Damian's work and published his extended, enhanced version in this blog post, [WCF and REST, An approach to using the Content-Type and Accept HTTP Headers for Object Serialization](http://daptivate.com/archive/2008/11/16/wcf-and-rest-an-approach-to-using-the-content-type-and-accept-http-headers-for-object-serialization.aspx). Excellent stuff.

Comment: http://daptivate.com/archive/2008/11/16/wcf-and-rest-an-approach-to-using-the-content-type-and-accept-http-headers-for-object-serialization.aspx not found