# WCF Service contract to be both XML and Json serialized

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest, serialization

How can I create the service contract to be in **XmlSerializerFormat** as well as **WebMessageFormat.Json** within a WCF RESTful service.

What I need is to call the "CallADSWebMethod" operation contract from code behind of ASP.Net 1.1 which needs to be XML serialized and
from jQuery ajax which is Json serialized.

SERVICE CONTRACT

```
[ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/CallADSWebMethod",
                   Method = "POST",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        VINDescription CallADSWebMethod(string vin, string styleID);
    }
```

**Endpoint Info**

```
        <endpoint address="basic"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  name="httpEndPoint"
                  contract="ADSChromeVINDecoder.IService" />
        <endpoint address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                  name="webEndPoint"
                  contract="ADSChromeVINDecoder.IService" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  address="mex" />
```

Comment: Suggest you go through this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008706/wcf-webinvoke-responseformat>

Comment: I would try by adding `behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpoint"` to json endpoint and inserting this `<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpEndpoint"> 
        <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true"  defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="True" />  
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>`

Comment: @L.B - I did added that, but than the "XmlSerializerFormat" in service contract is causing problem and showing..Operation 'CallADSWebMethod' (in contract 'IService' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') specifies the http body format to be JSON but the serialization mechanism for the operation is not DataContract. JSON format is only supported with DataContract serialization. If you have an XmlSerializerFormatAttribute on the operation consider replacing it with DataContractFormatAttribute

Comment: Do you mean you would like the service to return VINDescription object is both XML and JSON formats as response as needed?

Comment: Just remove the response format setting from the WebInvoke attribute and then the WCF framework will decide on which format to send the data back to client based on the Accept http header value. By default its XML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is specify your Web Service like this:

```
     [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
        UriTemplate = ""/CallADSWebMethod"")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = ""/CallADSWebMethod"")]
VINDescription CallADSWebMethod(string vin, string styleID);
    }
```

*However*, what I would suggest you to do is specify 2 different *endpoints*: one for the **XML** serialized data and another for **JSON** serialized data. Come on dude, you are using the ***REST architecture***.....why not make full use of it??!

Comment: I do have 2 endpoints..but it was not allowing for 2 different formats.

Comment: Can you have two WebInvoke attributes with the same method ?  I get a compilation error "Duplicate WebInvoke Attribute"

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done without a dual declaration as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719594/return-multiple-response-from-wcf) by setting the `webHttpBehavior`'s `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` property to `true`.