# Validate content type with WCF API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to validate that a request is either json or xml data for our api. I know I can do something along the lines of

```
if (!( request.ContentType.Equals("text/json", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || request.ContentType.Equals("text/xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    //throw error here
```

But, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. I read up about Content Management but everything I'm finding seems to be for web api.

To give you an example of why I don't like this approach, one of our clients passes in text/xml; charset=UTF-8 and another passes in text / xml
I can build checks for all of those but I was wondering if .net had anything built out there for this. I don't want to have to be hard coding something new, every new a new scenario comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options if you want to stick to one WCF implementation.

1- Define multiple endpoints for your WCF service. One for SOAP/XML and one for REST/JSON (recommended): [REST / SOAP endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service)

2- Define one endpoint but explicitly handle different content types: [WCF Service contract to be both XML and Json serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947438/wcf-service-contract-to-be-both-xml-and-json-serialized)